# How to add try and catch around if statement?

Tags: java

I am unable to surround the following if statement with try and catch statement. I still see the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextint();
int w = sc.nextint();
try {
 if(i == 2 && w == 3)
 {
  System.out.println(“Error. Please enter the missing elements.”);
 }
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
 System.out.println(“Error. Please try again.”);
}
```

Comment: error may be thrown also if input isn't number

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything with array in mentioned if statement. Exception is caused somewhere else.

Comment: @davidxxx fixed

Comment: It is better :)

Comment: No it does throw an error. I want to know how to fix the error. Please help!

Comment: If someone enters *i* but not *w*, this error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

A `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception that is thrown is a bug in your program that you have to correct.  It is not a exception to catch.
You should never refer to an index outside the boundaries of an array.

And whatever, as mentioned this code doesn't thrown any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.